# What's the difference between List take() vs. getRange() in Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, collections

I want the first *n* elements of some `List`. From what I can tell, I have two options: `take(n)` and `getRange(0, n)`.

1. What's the difference between them?
2. When would I use one over the other (assuming I always want the first *n* elements)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The most obvious difference is that `take()` can only use elements at the beginning, you can combine it with `skip()` like `list.skip(3).take(5)` to get similar behavior though.
`list.take()` is lazy evaluated which works nice with functional style programming and might be more efficient if the elements aren't actually iterated over later.
`list.take()` also is tolerant when there aren't as many elements in the list as requested. `take()` returns as many as available, `getRange()` throws.
`take()` is available on all iterables (also streams), `getRange()` is only available by default on list.